# Remove white spaces in table without affecting the other rows placement

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, I've been working on creating a clickable banner by using a table, but I'm having trouble getting rid of white spaces between my rows and spliced images.
This is what the table looks like in a browser

[image: Browser view of table]

And below is my code for the table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>A Spot Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><img src="images/top%20header%201.jpg" alt="TOP BANNER" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/top%20row%20left%20side%201.jpg" alt="SECOND BANNER" /></td>
                <td><a href="https://www.link.com/login"><img src="images/last%20image%20to%20line%20with%20top%20header%201.jpg" alt="THIRD BANNER" /></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.link.com/application"><img src="images/bottom%20row%20left%20side%202.jpg" alt="FOURTH BANNER" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried inline styling using padding and margin, but both seem to affect the placement of the other banners, specifically the third banner.
I'm quite new and not too sure what else to try, does anyone have any advice or resources I can use to figure this out?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. **Do not post images of code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this CSS:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Border-collapse will do just that: remove the space in between each of the table data (`<td>`) elements.
Padding will also remove any leftover space between these elements.